# rails 3 client side prototype validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, prototypejs, form-for

I can't seem to get js validations working on a form_for in Rails 3. Here's what I've got :

```
    <% form_for(:act, :remote => true, 
                :url => act_create_path, :condition => "return false", 
                :html => {:id => "newActForm"}) do |f| %>
```

I'm imagining that some change came in with :remote, but how do I run js validations? This was pretty straightforward in Rails 2.3... can't find any documentation or examples. Using Prototype, btw, no jQuery.

Comment: What have you tried? Specifically, what type of JS validation are you trying to perform, and on which elements of your form? If you look in rails.js on your site, you will see how the data-remote attribute on the form gets the form submit highjacked. You can certainly validate the entire form or the individual elements within it before the submission happens, but you'll need to show a lot more code here before I can suggest anything specific.